# AWS Athena not properly reading in datasets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Excuse the ignorance about the AWS stack in general. I am doing some basic technology exploration to determine feasibility of using it in some way in a non-tech oriented organization.

I've set up a Glue Crawler for one of my S3 buckets which has successfully crawled 5 or 6 files and entered tables into a database in my Data Lake. However, when I go to Athena to query the data, I'll sometimes get output view of data that's just a column of gibberish (from the hive backend I suppose?):

```
hive" item code* item code2bigint8@HP"'
```

Another time I just got rows of double quotations like so:

```
colA.    colB.    colC.   
""       ""       ""
```

Is there some kind of trick to getting data to read in properly? I'm testing with pretty simple CSVs and XLSX files. I've gone back through and checked all the crawler parameters and they seem to be correct. Is the issue with Athena or with Glue? I've also scoured every AWS guide I can find and googled the heck out of this without success. I'm sure it's probably relatively simple solution but it is evading me.

Thanks in advance for any helpful hints.

Comment: What is the file format that you are using and if possible upload a sample dataset to any public repo and share the link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Athena query returns results in incorrect format when query is run again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494792/aws-athena-query-returns-results-in-incorrect-format-when-query-is-run-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your query output is written to the same location as your dataset, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62495350/1109) for instructions on how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks; I had to select a different S3 bucket as the output location, rather than just a different folder in the same bucket.