# AWS Athena query returns results in incorrect format when query is run again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

The first time I ran the query, it returned 2 rows with columns names. I edited the table and added skip.header.line.count - 1 and reran(First time), but it returned same result with double inverted commas. Then reran again(Second time), and this changed everything.

First time Query run output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6T2O.png

Second time Query run output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cxrf.png

Comment: It is quite possible that the files in the Amazon S3 location are of different format. This might be caused by something else outputting data into that location (eg the Athena output files). Are you able to look at the files in that location and determine whether they are all of the same format? The filenames (Keys) might also look different.

Comment: So I checked the Athena Output files and there were a lot of metadata files. I deleted those and reran again. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Again, it worked the first time(Perfect query output). But why is Athena creating a folder named Unsaved(which has lot of metadata files) inside the S3 after I run second time ? And the query results after I run the same query second time are in the double inverted commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that output files from Amazon Athena are being mixed-in with your source files.

To fix it, go to the Athena console and click **Settings**.

Then, change the **Query result location** to a different location that does *not* point to the location where you are storing the source data files.

The Query result location is where Athena stores the output of queries, in case you need the results again or want to use them as input to future queries.